Probably caching issue with static Gatsby website
I have a Gatsby React website hosted in Azure blob storage, this static website is generated by Sanity. Users access this website through an Azure CDN. Whenever a change is made in sanity we see that the website is not updated with the latest content but the CDN and storage are updated as expected.
I am unable to figure out why.
We have tried purging the cache during Sanity build but it didn't help.
We also have an Azure function that triggers the build once the Sanity build is done.

refer to this link for Control Azure Content Delivery Network caching behavior with caching rules

Steps for hosting a Gatsby React website in Azure Blob Storage using Azure CDN:
Ensure Node.js and npm are installed. Install the Gatsby CLI globally using npm:
npm install -g gatsby-cli

After installing the Gatsby CLI, create a new Gatsby site by running the following command:
gatsby new my-gatsby-site

Once the new site is created, navigate into the directory of your newly created Gatsby site using the cd command:
cd my-gatsby-site

Start the development server by running the following command:
gatsby develop


Now, deploy the app to Azure Web App Service or Azure Static Web App.
.
Note: If there are changes in the web app make sure you build and deploy again. So it reflects the changes in the Azure web app.
Create an Azure Front Door profile using Azure Web App Service or Azure Static Web App by selecting the origin type and origin hostname.


In azure storage with  Front Door and CDN
Follow this steps :

creat a host of  static website in Azure Storage using this doc.


Note: For  gatsby  application the whole folder of  should be sent to $web .

Go to the     Azure Storage account andsearch for Front Door and CDN . Select use existing profile and select static website url




Select the existing details and create an Endpoint.

Refer to this link for controlling Azure Content Delivery Network caching behavior with caching rules.


